# Updating a list of objects bound to a DataGridView from a popup form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I seem to be having a bit of a problem with returning the updated information on my edit button placed on the popup form, back to my `DataGridView` (which is bound to a list of objects) on the original form.

I seemed to have it working the other day, however, i've come back to work on it today and it doesn't seem to be functional, I don't know whether this is because there is a flaw in my logic, or something has accidentally been deleted.

I have two forms. `Shopping Form.cs` and `Popup.cs`.

`Shopping Form.cs` displays a shopping basket in a `DataGridView` called `dataGridBasket` which is bound to a seperate `List<OrderItem>OrderItems` which comes from my `OrderItem` class. This can be added to by filling in the provided text boxes/numericUpDowns on the page `ProductName` `Quantity` and `LatestPrice` and then clicking the Add button `btnAdd`. It also has the ability to remove data from the selected row by clicking the Remove button `btnRemove`.

Here is the code from the `Shopping Form.cs`

```
#region Edit button
        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridBasket.CurrentRow;
            OrderItem oi = myBasket.OrderItems[dataGridBasket.SelectedRows[0].Index];
            if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {
                DialogResult dialogresult;
                Popup form = new Popup(row);
                dialogresult = form.ShowDialog();
                if (dialogresult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) 
                {
                    oi.ProductName = form.ProdName;
                    oi.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(form.QuantityE);
                    oi.LatestPrice = form.LatPrice;
                }
                else if (dialogresult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
                { 
                    form.Close();
                }
                form.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

And here is the `Popup.cs`

```
{
    public partial class Popup : Form
    {
        public Popup(DataGridViewRow rowToEdit)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            txtEditProdName.Text = rowToEdit.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            string quantityToEdit = rowToEdit.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            decimal iQuantityToEdit = Convert.ToDecimal(quantityToEdit);
            upDownEditQuantity.Value = iQuantityToEdit;            

            string latestPriceToEdit = rowToEdit.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtEditLatPrice.Text = latestPriceToEdit;            
        }

        public string ProdName { get { return txtEditProdName.Text; } }

        public decimal QuantityE { get { return upDownEditQuantity.Value; } }

        public decimal LatPrice { get { return Convert.ToDecimal(txtEditLatPrice.Text); } }
    }

}
```

The popup works just fine and the fields are populated with the information from the selected row, however, when the user updates the information and presses OK, the data on the original form does not change.

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the databound item does not contain notify property changed events, the user interface (datagridview) won't know anything has changed. You'll have to trigger the refresh manually. Either the entire grid or source or something like `dataGridBasket.InvalidateRow(SelectedRow.Index)`

Comment: @Me.Name Ah yes! silly me! I must have removed the rebind, I just added in `dataGridBasket.DataSource = null;` and then `dataGridBasket.DataSource = myBasket.OrderItems;` and it worked again. Thanks for your comment, add it as an answer so I can accept it! :)

Comment: Okidoki, copy pasted the comment ;) Glad it was of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the databound item does not contain notify property changed events, the user interface (datagridview) won't know anything has changed. You'll have to trigger the refresh manually. Either the entire grid or source or something like `dataGridBasket.InvalidateRow(row.Index)`